# Git merge take mine on everything

Tags: git, merge

Is there a git merge command that merges another branch into the current branch, but doesn't change any files?

Or in other words, I want to create a new commit on branch A with:

- The same tree (files) as latest commit on branch A
- Parent commit should be latest commit on branch A
- Other parent commit should be latest commit on branch B

---

Consider two long running branches one mine, one theirs. I want to merge their branch onto my branch, but since the code is effectively doing the same, I want to mark it as merged. The next time I'm merging again, it will not look back further than the merge commit that will be created in this process.

I know about `-X mine`/`--strategy-option=mine` but that will only kick in when there's an actual merge conflict. No added/deleted files should be applied on my branch.

Comment: My first thought was `git merge --no-commit theirs; git checkout mine .` but that will still add added files in `theirs` unless I am mistaken. Maybe you could just manually modify `.git/MERGE_HEAD` and then commit without making any changes? (Not an answer -- don't know if it will work)

Comment: You are describing `-s ours` (not `-X ours`, but `-s ours`, they are very different).

Comment: @torek Neat, are you able to post that as an answer?

Comment: Maybe better to just close as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23762897/1256452 ?

Comment: Not strictly a duplicate, but good enough for future reference. Once people hit this page, they'll be redirected to more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you're absolutely certain you don't want the `theirs`, you could perform the `merge` without committing, then checkout `mine` as-is, then complete the merge commit.

```
git merge --no-commit their-branch
git rm . -rf
git checkout HEAD -- .
git commit
```

The `git checkout HEAD -- .` will overwrite any conflicted or automatically modified files. Performing a `git status` at this point should reveal that nothing is modified, but that you are still mid-merge. The `commit` then completes your non-merge merge.

#### Edit: `git rm . -rf`

Originally, I had omitted any part of this workflow capable of removing entirely new files from `theirs`, as `git checkout HEAD -- .` would leave these intact.

The line `git rm . -rf` ensures that every file known to `git` at that time is removed. This will include removing any file which existed in `theirs` but not `ours`. We will then `checkout` only those from `ours`, and commit the resulting empty merge.

Comment: I'm still ending up with both files in the final branch: https://pastebin.com/FkMkVBhs

Comment: @Caramiriel you're right - I had to remove the `theirs` files - see the edit with an additional `git rm . -rf` step to clear the working directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can craft your own commit object with the details you desire. Here is how I do it manually

1. `git checkout A`

   - Start on the `A` branch
2. `git cat-file commit A > mine.commit`

   - This retrieves the current commit object to use as a starting point. It has most of what we want in our new commit object.
3. `git rev-parse B`

   - You need the output from this for `4.`
4. Edit `mine.commit` in your favorite text editor

   - This is the file you will put the information that satisfy your requirements
   - The `tree` line remains unchanged - this is the state of your repository at this commit
   - The first `parent` line remains unchanged - this is the commit-id of your A branch
   - Add another `parent` line with the hash code printed from `3.` above
   - Modify the `author`, `committer` lines if desired. Change the commit message at the bottom
5. `cat mine.commit | git hash-object -t commit --stdin -w`

   - This writes the commit object into your database and prints out its commit-id.
6. `git merge --ff-only <output from hash-object above>`

   - This should succeed and your `A` branch should be updated accordingly

Comment: That `git hash-object` is pretty nifty, I'm going to remember this. I think this solution works well when there's a lot of conflicts. `merge -s ours` seems to want me to "resolve" the conflicts (there are none, because of 'ours'), so this would be the better option. For less conflicting merges, I'd recommend the `merge -s ours` option though.

Comment: Absolutely, I would 100% suggest using `merge` commands over this manual process. This process I describe here is for when merge just doesn't want to do the job effectively, usually it works quite well.