# Git merge -no-ff transferred commit history, but not content

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, git-merge

Faced a bug in GitLab. One of my projects have over 50 modules. So when I merge branches, I use a bash script, instead of using the GitLab merge UI. This has worked fine so far. This time I faced a weird issue. The merge commit transferred the commit history from the source branch to the target branch, but not the content of the source branch. I was trying to merge the branch cr_integrate to the branch cr_release. Locally, I had cr_release checked out.

The script I used for merge is given below:

```
git pull
git merge --no-ff origin/cr_integrate -s ours
git add *
git commit -m "Integrate merged into Release by script"
git push
```

The project contains submodules, and the content of the **.gitmodules** file is different for different branches, hence I used **-s ours** to avoid conflict. Is there something wrong with the script or is this a bug with GitLab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hence I used `-s ours` to avoid conflict

But `-s ours` is not a conflict resolution strategy. It is a merge strategy.

I like reading the docs:

> the `ours` merge strategy ... does not even look at what the other tree contains at all. It *discards everything the other tree did*, declaring our history contains all that happened in it.

[emphasis mine]

So, now, you say:

> The merge commit transferred the commit history from the source branch to the target branch, but not the content of the source branch.

Yep. Because that’s what you said to do. Perhaps you meant `-s recursive -X ours`? That is a conflict resolution strategy.

Comment: And see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762897/git-merge-s-recursive-x-ours-vs-git-merge-s-ours

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did not know this.